# Why is simple_html_dom so slow?

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I am using simple_html_dom on a webpage of mine to save 3 separate pages and search and print various things within those pages. This makes the page take quite a few seconds to load.

Is there any way that I can optimize simple_html_dom to run faster? Or is there something else I should be using altogether for better speeds? I would think 3 pages isn't that much, but perhaps I am wrong. I guess it's like loading 3 separate pages all at one time — but then, is there anything at all that I can use to make things faster?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all you should search what exactly takes time. Downloading the file? Parsing it? Anything else you do? Could you also include your PHP code? It's hard to say if something is wrong without seeing it.

Comment: How can I know what it is that is taking the time? (Sorry if that's a stupid question — new to programming.) I could also show you the code, but there's quite a lot of it. It's generally a file_get_html and then a find-> within the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably depends on what you search for, i.e., how much DOM scraping the parser needs to do. I recently used simple_html_dom for extracting data from almost a thousand pages, all in a single request, and it took like 10 seconds to process it all.

It might be that the HTTP request takes most of the time. Try fetching the pages to scrape with `wget` or whatever's your preferred method, and then run simple_html_dom against files saved to your local hard disc.

Comment: The problem is that what I am scraping will be different every time, so I cannot save the files locally beforehand. What I am doing is saving the whole webpage (three of them), and then finding about a total of 5 lines of text from within the three pages I saved. I feel like it's taking far longer to do that than it should.

Comment: Have you tried putting some breakpoints or something similar? Like, maybe print the elapsed time after each page is fetched and again after it's scraped to see what exactly the bottleneck is. From my experience, it's almost always the http request (that's why I `wget` the pages first and then run everything locally).